# How to install font not part of TexLive - Mint 17.1

Tags: fonts

How do I install the fonts from the Latex Font Catalogue that are not part of texlive? In this particular instance I would like to use [Augie](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/augie/) which is part of the emerald package (though in future I want to use other fonts too.)

The following code gives the error "emerald.sty not found" so I assume I only have the texlive packages and not the others.

I have read about getnonfreefonts but this Augie font says it is free so I'm not sure.

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,article]{memoir} % for a short document

\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\pagestyle{empty}    

\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{%
\nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}    

\begin{document}    

\ECFAugie    

\renewcommand{\poemtitlefont}{\centering}
\poemtitle{Poem}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{Width}
line1\\
line2\\
line3
\end{verse}
\attrib{}

\end{document}
```

Thankyou.

Comment: `augie` is part of TeX Live.

Comment: The `emerald` package is not part of TL, but `augie` is. The font catalogue is wrong. `emerald` is not supported by `getnonfreefonts(-sys)`. You can install it yourself or just write `\newcommand\augie{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{augie}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}` in your preamble.

Comment: @cfr Thankyou, but I have tried that code both before and after \begin{document} and the font is not produced. I don't know how to install the emerald package myself which is what I was asking. Any further clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using upstream TeX Live or your distro's? If you have a full install from upstream, it should work. If you have installed packages from your distro, you may not have installed the right one for `augie` or they may (for some reason) have decided not to include it at all.

Comment: I installed it through my distro. I don't know anything about upstream sorry.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu. Otherwise, first try to figure out if your distro packages `augie`. It is part of TeX Live, after all.